# To extract the quarterly date from the string YYYYQ1 using shell script

Tags: shell, date

I need to extract the start date and end date from the below string format as shown below.

```
col1
2018Q1
2018_Q2
2018-Q3
```

so I need to get the output as below

```
col1,start_dt,end_dt
2018Q1, 2018-01-01 00:00:00, 2018-03-31 00:00:00
2018_Q2, 2018-04-01 00:00:00, 2018-06-30 00:00:00
2018-Q3, 2018-07-01 00:00:00, 2018-09-30 00:00:00
```

I have used search pattern to split the YYYY and quarterly information. So how to pass these values and get the aforesaid start_dt and end_dt.

Comment: shouldn't the end_dt column have times 23:59:59 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` to do the matching:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

(
  read -r header

  printf '%s,start_dt,end_dt\n' "${header}"

  while read -r date
  do
    case "${date}"
    in
      *Q1)
        beg=01-01
        end=03-31
        ;;

      *Q2)
        beg=04-01
        end=06-30
        ;;

      *Q3)
        beg=07-01
        end=09-30
        ;;

      *Q4)
        beg=10-01
        end=12-31
        ;;

      *)
        printf 'Bad format %s' "${date}" >&2
        exit2
    esac

    year="$(printf '%s' "${date}" | grep -o '^[[:digit:]]\+')"
    printf '%s, %d-%s 00:00:00, %d-%s 00:00:00\n' \
           "${date}" \
           "${year}" \
           "${beg}" \
           "${year}" \
           "${end}"
  done
) < file
```

Comment: whether this could be ok?

`date -d "20180101" '+%Y-%m-%d %T' ; date -d "$(date -d "20180131 2 month" '+%Y-%m-%d %T')" '+%Y-%m-%d %T' `

where 20180101 is derived using the search pattern of 2018_Q1 and add "0101" into it

Comment: Possibly. Did you try it? Why the `date -d "$(date -d …) …`, though?

Comment: I tried and below is output's

`$ date -d "20180101" '+%Y-%m-%d %T' ; date -d "$(date -d "20180131 2 month" '+%Y-%m-%d %T')" '+%Y-%m-%d %T'
2018-01-01 00:00:00
2018-03-31 00:00:00

$ date -d "20180401" '+%Y-%m-%d %T' ; date -d "$(date -d "20180430 2 month" '+%Y-%m-%d %T')" '+%Y-%m-%d %T'
2018-04-01 00:00:00
2018-06-30 00:00:00

$ date -d "20180701" '+%Y-%m-%d %T' ; date -d "$(date -d "20180731 2 month" '+%Y-%m-%d %T')" '+%Y-%m-%d %T'
2018-07-01 00:00:00
2018-10-01 00:00:00
 `

Comment: ` date -d "$(date -d …) …`

This is to get the end_dt

Comment: I tried the below one also

`date -d "20181001" '+%Y-%m-%d %T' ; date -d "$(date -d "20181001 3 month -1 day" '+%Y-%m-%d %T') " '+%Y-%m-%d %T' `

please let me know are we good to use the above format for each Quarterly. Also I could use sed and cut to rearrange into comma separated.

Comment: I dont’t understand what you’re asking: If you have some code that works, go ahead and use it. What do you want from me?!

Comment: Since I am intermediate in shell scripting. Just to verify the code written is fine?